Use a button to change a library webpart view on a SharePoint Online site
My SPO site has a Library view set to All Documents. The library, named Log, has several views. Cat-1, Cat-2, Cat-3, etc. Is it possible to have buttons on the site, one for each Cat#, that when clicked changes the Library view from All Documents to the specific Cat# view?
Clarifying information. My SPO site has a Document Library Web Part set to the All Documents view. I need buttons above the Document Library Web Part that changes the view the Doc Library Web Part is set to on the site without opening the document library. I have buttons set to URLs now. these buttons open the document library, I am trying to avoid that.

Yes, in the library, select the view from the view dropdown. That's what it's made for.
If you want a button on a different page that goes to that specific view, use the URL of that view for the link.
